# How to traceroute in SDN Networks while traceroute is not working in SDN by default?

Tags: traceroute, sdn

I have used all opendaylight, floodlight and POX controllers one by one in my SDN ring topology which is created by mininet, but I am not able to use traceroute command and trace the paths where the ping packets transferred.

In this article

SDN Traceroute: [Tracing SDN Forwarding Without Changing Network Behavior](http://ericrozner.com/papers/sdn-traceroute-hotsdn-2014-final.pdf)

it is said that they have created a method to traceroute the SDN, but it is so hard to apply.

any other suggestion?

Comment: If the TTL does not get decremented, then traceroute will not work. That is specifically the very essence of how traceroute works. It could also lead to other problems, like routing loops that will never end.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

One of the points of SDN is that you build a virtual "network box" where all your switching, routing, NATing, etc happens and that looks like a single device from the outside, regardless of its physical components and their locations.

Obviously, that's detrimental to tools like traceroute that depend on distinct L3 hops they can trace. Usually, a SDN solution has its own tools to trace or simulate flows across the network. There's no standard for this (yet), however.

Also, you might be able to configure special rule sets that allow you to trace traffic across the net (like the paper you linked to proposes). Alternatively, you could deliberately decrement and check TTL to make a "hop" appear in traceroute. How that may or may not work depends on your SDN solution.

Comment: what are those SDN solutions to allow us to trace the traffic? what do you mean about linked paper? how can I artificially decrement and check TTL? I know the general points, but I want an exact procedure (step by step solutions)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with specific solutions, just the general concept, sorry, and product recommendations are off-topic here anyway. I was referring to the paper you've linked in your question and thought you'd read it. Surely you can manipulate TTL in an SDN flow to simulate an L3 hop.